# When converts ASP.NET values of ValueProvider?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-binding

My project uses ASP.NET MVC.

I´m sending some data via ajax to a controller-action which looks like

```
{ "data" : { "DATE" : "\/Date(1409097600000)\/", "NAME" : "thomas } }
```

I use the ValueProvider of the controller to process the data:

```
var provider = ControllerContext.Controller.ValueProvider;
var value = provider.GetValue("data.DATE");
// value is now already "27.08.2014 00:00:00"
```

Why?

Where does this part of conversion happens?

Similar question to that :-

The data above is as content type `"application/json; charset=utf=8"`

Having data as `"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf=8"` ASP.NET is not able to convert the date-values.

```
 _model.DATE=%5C%2FDate(1409097600000)%5C%2F&_model.NAME=thomas
```

I think I made something wrong concerning the `\` and `/` in the .NET-date-format: `\/Date(1409097600000)\/`

*(I know netwonsoft.json could be an alternative for javascript-serialization, but unfortunately not at the moment)*

Comment: (1409097600000 / 1000) = 1409097600 = unix timestamp = 27.08.2014 00:00:00 :)

Comment: Nice (I that is not unknown to me ;) )- but I´m pointing a different challenge ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you are sending JSON data to the server using an Ajax post, then the content-type header should reflect that fact (Content-Type="application/json; charset=utf=8"), so that the server interprets the data correctly.

Content-Type="application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf=8", is for submitting data via an HTML form. If you submit your JSON data with this content type header, the browser will url-encode it and produce the string you illustrated:

```
_model.DATE=%5C%2FDate(1409097600000)%5C%2F&_model.NAME=thomas
```

The Date() function has no meaning in an HTTP form post (it is a JSON function) which is why the date conversion fails.

Comment: Changing content-type should be enough? No change of formatting required? Is not easy - unfortunately ajax-post is done by third-party-component :/

Comment: Check the configuration options for your 3rd party component. If it is sending json data, it should be setting the headers to reflect the fact.